# Flutter Firebase refresh document snapshot every 24h

Tags: flutter, firebase, refresh, document, snapshot

I have a recipe collection with 100 entries in firebase firestore. The idea is that the user only sees 3 different recipes in my app. Those 3 recipes need to change every 24h.
So on Monday the user sees 3 (different) recipes from my collection, on Tuesday the next 3 (randomly chosen) recipes and so on. How is that possible to achieve?

Comment: Do you want all users to see the same three recipes that change daily?  Or should each user have their own 3 items?

Comment: Ideally everyone should see the same recipes

Answer (score 0):

Simply store another field called '`lastRefresh`' in a document for each user.

The value of that field will be a `DateTime`, of course you have to format it to a string with `DateTime().toIso8601String()` to store it on Firestore.

Then on app start get the value and parse it to `DateTime` again with
`DateTime.parse(value_from_firestore)` and get the difference to now.
You can achieve this by calling `DateTime.now().difference(parsed_date_time_from_firestore)` which will return a duration.

You can check wheter this duration is greater then 24 hours. If it is, load another 3 recipes from firestore and set lastRefresh with `DateTime.now().toIso8601String()` to now again.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I do not store user data in firebase - only the recipes. But I use Hive on various places in my app. I think this should also work with the date value, shouldn't it?

Comment: I never used Hive before, but you can try it out